# Sort each range of vector

Tags: matlab, sorting

Given the following vector:

```
5 4 1 2 3 1 4 5 3 2 3 2 1 5 4
_________ _________ _________
```

I want to apply sort on each 5 elements of the vector. So the out put would be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 
_________ _________ _________
```

How to achieve this without loops in MATLAB?

P.S. I want also to extract the sorting indices to apply them on another vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to avoid loops, you could use a combination of `reshape` and `sort` to achieve what you want:

```
b = [5 4 1 2 3 1 4 5 3 2 3 2 1 5 4];
b2 = reshape(b, [5 3]);           % Reshape your array to be a [5x3] matrix
b2_new = sort(b2, 1);             % Sort each column of your matrix seperately
b_new = reshape(b2_new, size(b)); % Reshape the outcome back to the original dimensions
```

Or, all in one line:

```
b_new = reshape(sort(reshape(b, [5 3]), 1), size(b));
```

You would have to change the numbers 5 and 3 to be appropriate for your problem, of course. It is important to make sure that the first value you give in for the reshaping command (`5` in this case) equals the length of the sub-vectors that you want to sort, as Matlab is column major.

**Edit:**

If you want to sort one particular vector, and then apply the same reordering to other vectors, you can use the optional second output argument of the `sort` function. Working with the same vectors as above:

```
b = [5 4 1 2 3 1 4 5 3 2 3 2 1 5 4];
b2 = reshape(b, [5 3]);
```

yields:

```
b2 = 5 1 3
     4 4 2
     1 5 1
     2 3 5
     3 2 4
```

Say you want to sort the first column, and apply the same reordering to the second and third, you do:

```
[~,idx] = sort( b2(:,1) );   % Sorts the first column of b2, and stores the index map in 'idx'
```

This will yield `idx = [3 4 5 2 1]`. Now you can use these indices to sort all columns:

```
b2_new = b2(idx,:);
b2_new =
     1     5     1
     2     3     5
     3     2     4
     4     4     2
     5     1     3
```

And finally, you can use `reshape` back to the original dimensions:

```
b_new = reshape(b2_new, size(b));
```

---

**Edit 2:**

If you want to store the reordering of `b` as a whole, and apply it to a new vector `c`, we will have to get a bit more creative. The following is one approach:

```
b = [5 4 1 2 3 1 4 5 3 2 3 2 1 5 4];
b2, = reshape(b, [5 3]);

% Sort each column of your matrix seperately, and store the index map
[~,idx] = sort(b2, 1);

% Alter the index map, such that the indices are now linear indices:
idx = idx + (0:size(idx,2)-1)*size(idx,1);

% Reshape the index map to the original dimensions of b:
idx = reshape(idx, size(b));

% Now sort any array you want using this index map as follows:
b_new = b(idx);
c_new = c(idx);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to extract the sorting vector (reshaped) to apply it to another vector that I need to sort in the same manner I sort the first vector?

Comment: I mean the second output of the sort function which contains the indices.

Comment: Is this what you meant, Humam? I was not completely sure. If you want to store the entire re-ordering of `b`, and apply it to a different vector `c`, we will have to get a bit more creative.

Comment: Yes I want the other option. However, from your idea. I could find the solution of the other problem. I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I figured. No problem! I have made a second edit that shows one approach you could take. You could use it as a check and try something yourself too :-)